# To Build a Lorem Ipsum Text Generator With JavaScript and Vite

Tags: vite

I am following the following link

[https://www.makeuseof.com/javascript-vite-build-lorem-ipsum-text-generator/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2xDe.jpg)

to create a Lorem Ipsum Text Generator With JavaScript and Vite.

Here, is the GitHub link of the source files of the above article:

https://github.com/makeuseofcode/muo-lorem-ipsum

Here, is the link of netlify app of the generator created by the author.

https://muo-lorem-ipsum.netlify.app

It works on Netlify app created by the author.

But I am failing to make this work. Even in the Command Line, VS Code, GitPages, and Netlify.

When I increase or decrease the sliders and click generate, it reverts to the defaults 25 and 3. Even Lorem Ipsum text is not shown.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

[image]